# Why is this Pascal Triangle implementation giving me trailing zeroes?

Tags: c++, recursion, pascals-triangle

I tried to implement it recursively (iteratively seemed less elegant, but please do correct me if I am wrong).But the output seems to be giving me trailing zeroes and the first few rows are unexpected.I have checked the base cases and the recursive cases , but they seem to be all right.The problem is definitely within the function.

```
#include <iostream>
unsigned long long p[1005][1005];
void pascal(int n)
{
    if (n == 1)
    {
        p[0][0] = 1;
        return;
    }
    else if (n == 2)
    {
        p[0][0] = 1; p[0][1] = 1;
        return;
    }
    p[n][0] = 1;
    p[n][n-1] = 1;
    pascal(n-1);
    for (int i = 1; i < n;++i)
    {
        p[n][i] = p[n-1][i-1] + p[n-1][i];
    }
    return;
}
int main()
{
    int n;
    std::cin >> n;
    pascal(n);
    for (int i = 0 ; i < n ; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0 ;j < i+1 ; ++j)
        {
            std::cout << p[i][j] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
}
```

Output:
(I enter)15

```
1
0 0
0 0 0
1 0 0 0
1 1 0 0 0
1 2 1 0 0 0
1 3 3 1 0 0 0
1 4 6 4 1 0 0 0
1 5 10 10 5 1 0 0 0
1 6 15 20 15 6 1 0 0 0
1 7 21 35 35 21 7 1 0 0 0
1 8 28 56 70 56 28 8 1 0 0 0
1 9 36 84 126 126 84 36 9 1 0 0 0
1 10 45 120 210 252 210 120 45 10 1 0 0 0
1 11 55 165 330 462 462 330 165 55 11 1 0 0 0
```

Comment: Done!My apologies

Comment: Thanks, can you add the expected output as well?

Answer (score 3):

The base cases `n = 1` and `n = 2` are too aggressive (1 is never reached for a normal input like 10 because 2 breaks the recursion prematurely, leaving untouched zeroes in the array). These values for `n` should be covered automatically by the recursive case. Our real base case where we do nothing is when `n < 0`.

```
void pascal(int n)
{   
    if (n < 0) return;

    p[n][0] = 1;
    pascal(n - 1);

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
    {
        p[n][i] = p[n-1][i-1] + p[n-1][i];
    }
}
```

Output for `n = 15`:

```
1
1 1
1 2 1
1 3 3 1
1 4 6 4 1
1 5 10 10 5 1
1 6 15 20 15 6 1
1 7 21 35 35 21 7 1
1 8 28 56 70 56 28 8 1
1 9 36 84 126 126 84 36 9 1
1 10 45 120 210 252 210 120 45 10 1
1 11 55 165 330 462 462 330 165 55 11 1
1 12 66 220 495 792 924 792 495 220 66 12 1
1 13 78 286 715 1287 1716 1716 1287 715 286 78 13 1
```

Having said this, it's poor practice to [hard code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_coding) the size of the array. Consider using vectors and passing parameters to the functions so that they don't mutate global state.

We can also write it iteratively in (to me) a more intuitive way:

```
void pascal(int n)
{   
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        p[i][0] = 1;

        for (int j = 1; j <= i; ++j)
        {
            p[i][j] = p[i-1][j-1] + p[i-1][j];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your indexes are off by one. The actual output when compiled will result in first line being 0, and each following line having a trailing 0.

Comment: The OP has hardcoded the first line to be at index 0, 0 of the array, but you removed his edge case. In your code, when n == 1 the result will be placed at index 1, 0 of the array. But OP original loop in `main` prints from 0, 0

Comment: I see what you mean--I changed the loop in `main` inadvertently which adjusted the print incorrectly and forgot I'd done so. Will update momentarily and thanks for pointing this out.